# python.exe has stopped working when opened via cmd

Tags: python, cmd

About two days ago Python stopped responding after I tried to open it in cmd. I tried reinstalling Python and searched the Internet for a possible solution, but found no answers. This problem is still going on.

[image: Python not responding]

[image: Event details]

Comment: Have you tried installing a different version / to a different location / running the embedded version (Python 3 in a zip)? Did you install anything 2 days ago (conflicting path to other python [dlls])?

Comment: Does Python work elsewhere when it is installed such as in Idle?

Comment: It works everywhere except cmd. When I open python.exe from file explorer it works entirely fine.

Comment: I installed colorama and ansicon 2 days ago but then I reinstalled Python and removed this library.

Comment: I usually work with Python 2.7 and I now tried installing version 3.6 instead and the problem just won't go!

Comment: Check for an autorun in cmd's HKLM or HKCU registry key: `reg query "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun`.

Comment: I found autorun and the data in it is: (if %ANSICON_VER%==^%ANSICON_VER^% "C:\ansi\x64\ansicon" -p). Should I delete it?

Comment: I deleted this value and it helped! Thank you very much, eryksun!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this download/open the python installer (corresponding to the version of your python). Once opened click `Repair`. This will repair Python.

If you are still experiencing trouble, try doing this:
1. Open the installer
2. Click on `Modify`
3. Check the button that says `Add Python to environmental variables`.